# Where is the blade/spindle lock on an old Skilsaw 5250 7 1/4" circular saw?

Tags: circular-saw

I have a Skilsaw 5250 7 1/4" circular saw i picked up used 20 years ago. No idea how old it is, but still works.

I recently put a metal grinding blade on it to cut roofing tin. Worked great. But now I want to put the saw blade back on. Never saw a blade lock button, so always used a Phillips screwdriver through one of the holes in blade to "lock" it while tightening/un-tightening the blade nut.

The metal grinding blade has no such holes. I Can't find a way to secure the blade/spindle while trying to loosen the nut.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It likely does not have a spindle lock.  I have a similar saw and there isn't one.  I use a heavy rag or glove to block the blade while adjusting the bolt.

Comment: A block of wood in the teeth can work also, or a screwdriver in the gullet.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, my first thought as well, but its a metal grinding blade, so it probably doesn't have teeth.

Comment: @Jason oh "grinding blade" doh missed that! :)

Answer (score 9):

I just use a vise-clamp to grab the blade and rotate till it is block by the saw plate.  This is always secure and never slips.

Answer (score 1):

Use pliers or channel locks to grab the metal grinding blade

You can also place the blade into a saw kerf that you cut with the same blade, then twist/rotate the saw slightly to bind the blade in the kerf

Don't forget to that the bolt is reversed threaded (don't accidentally tighten it down more! It happens to the best of us)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it probably has a hexagonal piece on the shaft on the side of the blade closest to the motor. Then, you use a special wrench that is very thin to hold on to that as you unscrew the nut.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't get enough holding power with the heavy rag / glove method, you can also use a scrap piece of wood (or metal) and wedge it between the blade and the shoe in order to hold the blade stationary.

Comment: won't work unfortunately as the metal grinding blade has no teeth